# Any other icon characters like '⚠️'

Tags: icons, character, emoji

We can output this icon characters, like Emoji on console. For example, on Mac terminal console

echo ⚠️
⚠️

Is there any other characters like '⚠️', so that I can use in shell scripts.

Comment: Those aren't emoji, they're UTF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Incidentally, emoji work fine. http://zachholman.com/posts/abusing-emoji/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9728
http://www.utf8icons.com/

We can use those characters in text files or console.